# Catch-all or default routing

Tags: haskell, servant

These days it's not uncommon to need to return a file (say, `index.html`) from the backend if the requested route doesn't match an existing API endpoint or another static asset. This is especially handy when using [`react-router`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) and [`browserHistory`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory).

I'm a bit stumped as to how I might approach this with Servant. I did wonder if intercepting 404's might be the way to go, but then of course sometimes the API will need to legitimately issue 404. Here's the kind of thing I've been using to experiment:

```
data Wombat = Wombat
  { id :: Int
  , name :: String
  } deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)
instance ToJSON Wombat

wombatStore :: [Wombat]
wombatStore = 
  [ Wombat 0 "Gertrude"
  , Wombat 1 "Horace"
  , Wombat 2 "Maisie"
  , Wombat 3 "Julius"
  ]

wombats :: Handler [Wombat]
wombats = return wombatStore

wombat :: Int -> Handler Wombat
wombat wid = do
  case find (\w -> Main.id w == wid) wombatStore of
    Just x -> return x
    Nothing -> throwE err404

type API = 
    "api" :> "wombats" :> Get '[JSON] [Wombat] :<|>
    "api" :> "wombats" :> Capture "id" Int :> Get '[JSON] Wombat :<|>
    Raw

api :: Proxy API
api = Proxy

server :: Server API 
server = wombats
  :<|> wombat
  :<|> serveDirectory "static"

app :: Application
app = serve api server

main :: IO ()
main = run 3000 app
```

I'd love to see an example of how I could go about adding a 'default route' that sends an HTML response if the request doesn't match an API endpoint or anything in the static directory. Toy repo [here](https://github.com/richchurcher/servant-routes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it, basically. `serveDirectory "static"` can be replaced by any wai `Application`, so for instance, we could have:

```
...
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
...
import Network.Wai        (responseLBS)
import Network.HTTP.Types (status200)
...
server :: Server API 
server = wombats
    :<|> wombat
    :<|> hello

hello :: Application
hello req respond = respond $ 
  responseLBS 
  status200                        -- 
  [("Content-Type", "text/plain")] -- headers
  "Hello, World!"                  -- content
...
```

To a first approximation, wai applications are simply `Request -> Response`, but [the docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.1.1/docs/Network-Wai.html#t:Application) tell a fuller story:

```
Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived
```

So since you've got access to IO, you can check if the file exists and if so serve it, otherwise do whatever you like. In fact, wai defines `type Middleware = Application -> Application`, so you might think up a handy Middleware that wraps up `hello` (or any other Application!) in a file existence-checker-and-server.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another route:

`serveDirectory` is defined as

```
serveDirectory = staticApp . defaultFileServerSettings . addTrailingPathSeparator
```

[`defaultFileServerSettings`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.9/wai-app-static-3.1.6.1/src/WaiAppStatic.Storage.Filesystem.html#defaultFileServerSettings) contains a field `ssLookupFile` which you can change to serve what you want if the file was not found. Perhaps:

```
import WaiAppStatic.Types
import WaiAppStatic.Storage.Filesystem
import Network.Wai.Application.Static
import System.FilePath

fileOrIndex root pieces = do
  res <- ssLookupFile (defaultFileServerSettings root) pieces
  case res of
    LRNotFound -> undefined -- index.html here
    _ -> return res

serveStatic root =
  let root' = addTrailingPathSeparator root in
  staticApp $ (defaultFileServerSettings root') {ssLookupFile = fileOrIndex root'}
```